# Docker image multi-stage building, FROM keyword not works with AS keyword

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm trying to start a service at the docker container. My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS dotnet_builder
WORKDIR /app/

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./Consumer/*.csproj ./Consumer/
COPY ./Lab.Shared/*.csproj ./Lab.Shared/

RUN dotnet restore ./Consumer/Consumer.csproj

# Copy everything else and build
COPY  ./Consumer ./Consumer/
COPY ./Lab.Shared ./Lab.Shared/

RUN dotnet publish ./Consumer/Consumer.csproj -c Release -o /publish/

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-alpine3.13

COPY --from=dotnet_builder /publish/ /app/

WORKDIR /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Consumer.dll"]
```

But if I try to use the command `docker build -t lab -f Dockerfile .` it doesn`t work. The error is

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 5.968 MB
Step 1: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS dotnet_builder
Pulling repository mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk
Error: image dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS dotnet_builder not found
```

Please, help me to understand where’s the trouble in my dockerfile

Comment: What is the output of `docker version`

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons docker daemon merge the image name with the multistage annotation "AS dotnet_builder", it's a random issue in docker build just wrap the image name by quotes and it will solve the problem

```
FROM 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0' AS dotnet_builder
```